# Substring Removal from a string using stream buffer class in java-Output wrong-Verify

Tags: java

Substring Removal from a string using stream buffer class in java.
Output coming wrong:

[image]

Please verify this Program

See my output and explain what the program is about?
What must be the desired output and what changes must be made in the program to get the corrct output?

```
import java.io.*;
public class Strbuff
{
    public static void main(String arg[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str;
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your name");
            str=in.readLine();
            str+="\nThis is example for string Buffer class and its function";
            StringBuffer strbuf=new StringBuffer();
            strbuf.append(str);
            System.out.println(strbuf);
            strbuf.delete(0,str.length());
            strbuf.append("hello");
            strbuf.insert(5,"-java");
            System.out.println(strbuf);
            strbuf.reverse();
            System.out.println("Reversed string");
            System.out.println(strbuf);
            strbuf.reverse();
            System.out.println(strbuf);
            strbuf.setCharAt(5,' ');
            System.out.println(strbuf);
            System.out.println("Character at 6th position");
            System.out.println(strbuf.substring(3,7));
            strbuf.deleteCharAt(3);
            System.out.println(strbuf);
            System.out.println("Capacity of the string Buffer object");
            System.out.println(strbuf.capacity());
            strbuf.delete(6,strbuf.length());
            System.out.println("The string with first 6 letters");
            System.out.println(strbuf);
        }
        catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "What must be the desired output and what changes must be made in the program to get the corrct output?" It's your program: how should we know what you want it to do?

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: Actually,Explain this topic:
Substring Removal from a string using stream buffer class in java
and is my o/p related to it??

Answer (score 0):

This is basic beginner material and you must have already covered and touched onto the methods that will allow you to establish what this code does. At the very least you will have been provided with (or the location of) the reading material you require to carry out the requested task.

All you need to do is actually do what is asked of you. Instead, you thought you would come to StatckOverflow and have someone else do your homework for you which is not what the forum is for. We are here to help you with the stumbling blocks you trip over while walking on your path to being a Java Programmer but, you must at the very least show an attempt to pick yourself up when you stumble. Copy/Pasting your homework code here is not considered trying.

Step through each line of code and place a comment consisting of a brief description of what that line does over each line. If you don't know what the code line does then read about the method you are having trouble with. Try different things with that method and before you know it, you will have a full understanding of it.

I will help get you started:

```
// Open a BufferReader InputStream and establish it as variable 'in'... 
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

// Declare a String variable named 'str'. This string is not originally
//initialized so I'm going to do that now with a Null String...
String str = "";

// Establish a try/catch block to trap a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
// should it ever occur. This exception is thrown by String methods to
// indicate that an index is either negative or greater than the size of
// the string. For some methods such as the charAt method, this exception
// also is thrown when the index is equal to the size of the string. We
// want to catch this exception so it doesn't crash our program...
try {

    // Print to the display console for User to enter his/her name...
    System.out.println("Enter your name");

    // Read what the User supplied and place the text into our 'str' 
    // String variable...
    str=in.readLine();

    // Add (append) the string "\nThis is example for string Buffer class 
    // and its function" to the 'str' string variable. The '\n' is a output
    // string tag for establishing a new line within the displayed output.
    // the '+=' attached to our 'str' variable is a Assignment Operator. It
    // tells the compiler to adds the right operand to the left operand and
    // assign the result to left operand. It is the same as writing:
    // str = str + "\nThis is example for string Buffer class and its function";
    str+="\nThis is example for string Buffer class and its function";

    // Establish a String Buffer and name it 'strbuf. A StringBuffer is a 
    // thread-safe, mutable sequence of characters. A string buffer is like a 
    // String, but can be modified...
    StringBuffer strbuf=new StringBuffer();

    // Place our current string held within the 'str' string variable into our
    // new String Buffer (strbuf). The StringBuffer.append() method is used for
    // this...
    strbuf.append(str);

    // Print the contents within out string buffer (strbuf) to the display 
    // console...
    System.out.println(strbuf);

    // Now Delete (clear) everything within our String Buffer variable (strbuf).
    // This is done using the StringBuffer.delete() method. 0 indicates the starting
    // point index for the number of characters within the string we want to delete.
    // The 'str.length()' portion indicates the ending index point to delete. The 
    // 'str.length()' method always returns the length of (number of characters) within
    // the string variable (str). So, we know our string variable 'str' contains:
    // the User provided name, let's say: "Vikraman" plus "\nThis is example for string 
    // Buffer class and its function" which in total is 66 characters in length but
    // because indexing always starts from 0 the length of the string (str) is 65. Our
    // line below could be written strbuff.delete(0, 65). Delete characters within the
    // string buffer variable (strbuf) starting from index 0 (the first character) to 
    // index 65 (the last character).
    strbuf.delete(0,str.length());

    ....................................
    ....................................
    ........  You Do The Rest  .........
    ....................................
    ....................................

}
catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    // Display the exception message to console.
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Yes...The comments are excessive and archaic but by the time you are done with it you will be a professional with that piece of code. ;)